# Is built-in entity selection clever or uniformly random?

Tags: optaplanner, timefold

Are the entity selectors for the built in move selectors (primarily interested in swap move and change move) clever in any way, or always uniformly random?

Do they for example take the indictment map into account?

If it's uniformly random, are there any subtle downsides to creating a custom entity selector that is biased towards picking problematic entities?

(I realize that it might be good to keep a small probability of selecting non-problematic entities to allow Timefold to escape local optima, but right now I suspect that my LS wastes a lot of time shuffling around entities that are fine where they are.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, none of the moves selectors take indictments into account. What you're describing is called [guided local search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guided_local_search) and it would likely bring benefits both to your use case and to [Timefold](https://timefold.ai/) as a whole.

If fact, we've been thinking about writing such a selector, but other priorities always interfered. If you're considering working on this, I wouldn't mind taking a look at your implementation and maybe integrating it into the upstream codebase.

Comment: Thanks Lukáš. I'll do some experiments first and see how it goes.